# Casting works but declaring type doesn't autocast variables

Tags: typescript, types, casting

I'm new to typescript and while I was making a canvas game for fun I encountered just at the begining a weird thing.

```js
// 1) Works but stores HTMLElement, so later fails
const canvas = document.getElementById("game"); 
// 2) Don't works
const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById("game");
// 3) Works
const canvas = document.getElementById("game") as HTMLCanvasElement; 
// 4) Works
const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById("game") as HTMLCanvasElement;
```

The awnser is why the second one doesn't work, shouldn't it try to autocast to the declared type? I think the last two ones are too verbose or not very clear. I'd like to know if there is a compiler option or if this is just happening to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are sure of the type of the element having a given selector, you can add an overload that maps the selector to the type in question: `declare global { interface Document { getElementById(id: "game"): HTMLCanvasElement; } }` in which case you don't need a type assertion.

Comment: One thing you could to as well:

```const element = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas');```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because compiler doesn't know type of your html tag with `id=game` in runtime.

getElementById signature looks like:

```
getElementById(elementId: string): HTMLElement | null;
```

[details here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/dom-manipulation.html#documentgetelementbyid)

and in typescript `HTMLElement | null` is not assignable to `HTMLCanvasElement`, because `HTMLCanvasElement` is just one of subtypes (and it can be null to)

If you are sure, that you tag always is of type `HTMLCanvasElement` you can tell to compiler

> Hey man! I know that this function always return `HTMLCanvasElement` in runtime. Trust me!

And you can use one of your working examples with `as` keyword

Answer (score 1):

Well, `document.getElementById` returns HtmlElement or null. It is not a generic method which is able to return HtmlCanvasElement.

So the type of first line should be HtmlElement | null.

As HtmlCanvasElement extends HtmlElement and not the other way around. The second line is not working.

Line 3 & 4 is the same but contain potential risk because, the ide does not help to should you a variable could be null => runtime error. and sure if you would call something only defined on HtmlCanvasElement but the id would not a HtmlCanvasElement you would see a runtime error again.

And at the end you should know typescript & types are only at development time. It helps you developing stuff. At the end it is javascript in you browser having know idea about types javascript cannot understand.